# T-SQL: How can I match itemsets with transaction lists?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table with item lists (= transactions) and a second one with subgroups of items (= itemsets).
As result I need a new table (= result set)  showing all the transactions which contains the items from table 'itemset', e.g. the items 'a' and 'f' are part of transaction 1 and 5, 'a' is part of transaction 1,2,4,5 and so forth....

How can I solve this with T-SQL?

**table1: transactions**

```
TID            itemlist   
1              a,c,f
2              a
3              c,f,g,h,l
4              b,a,c
5              f,a
```

**table2: itemset**

```
SID            item1   item2   item3 ......... item n 
1              a
2              c       l
3              c       f       l 
4              a       f
```

**result set:**

```
SID   TID
1     1
1     2
1     4
1     5
2     3
3     3
4     1
4     5
```

Comment: Your database design has serious flaws and should be refactored.  I would not solve this with T-SQL but rather by redesigning your database.  You will continue to face problems with this design.

Comment: was a vertical table better or a binary matrix? What you would propose?

Comment: Hrrm, I'm not quite sure what you mean by those things.  Basically you need to break your `itemList` column into a new table where each comma separated value is it's own row.

Comment: no problem, I have that already. But what then?

Comment: Then its the same with itemset. Your table design is extremely inefficient. You should have a table with one item per row. If you have that, the query your are looking for is trivial.

Comment: If I make an INNER JOIN betweenn these two tables (one item per row) I don't get the desired result. What I need are the transactions which contain ALL items from the itemsets not ANY item

Comment: What would really help here (other than some serious normalization) is ddl and sample data along with the desired result. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This won't fit in a comment, but as an example of what Abe means. If you had two tables TransItem and ItemSet like so:

```
TID     ItemId
1       a
1       c
1       f
2       a
```

and

```
SID     ItemID
1       a
2       c
2       l
```

Then the result set is simply a comparison of the set items with the transaction items

```
with SetItems
    as (select sid
                ,  count(sid) as itemcount 
        from ItemSet 
        group by sid)
, TransSet as (
        Select tid
                , sid
                , count(tid) transcount
        from 
            ItemSet s INNER JOIN 
            TransItem t ON s.Itemid=t.Itemid
        group by sid, tid )
Select s.sid, t.tid
from SetItems s LEFT OUTER JOIN 
TransSet t on s.sid=t.sid
where itemcount=transcount
order by sid, tid
```

It goes without saying, that if you have the items in columns, or as a comma delimited field, this query becomes way more difficult.

Comment: Sean, thank you very much. I just tried it out with a bigger data set and it works perfectly. I had the idea wiht the count as well, but absolutely no plan how to realize that with an appropriate SQL-code.

Comment: Part2: To transform my itemset-table into a vertical table I will take the UNPIVOT porposed by M.Ali. So with the input of both of you I am finally rid of this problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

### Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]  
    (  
      @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),  
      @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)  
    )   
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))  
AS  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @xml XML  
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'  

  INSERT INTO @t(val)  
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item  
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)  
  RETURN  
END
```

### Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #transactions  (TID INT, itemlist VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #transactions VALUES   
(1 ,'a,c,f'),
(2 ,'a'),
(3 ,'c,f,g,h,l'),
(4 ,'b,a,c'),
(5 ,'f,a')

CREATE TABLE #itemset([SID] INT, item1 VARCHAR(1), item2 VARCHAR(1), item3 VARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #itemset VALUES
(1 ,'a', NULL,  NULL),
(2 ,'c', 'l' ,  NULL),
(3 ,'c', 'f' ,  'l' ),
(4 ,'a', NULL,  'f')
```

### Query

```
;WITH TIDs AS (
    SELECT t.TID
          ,c.Items
    FROM #transactions t
           CROSS APPLY (SELECT Val FROM dbo.Split(t.itemlist , ',')) c(Items)
  ),
SIDs AS (
    SELECT [SID]
           ,Items
    FROM #itemset t
     UNPIVOT ( Items FOR item IN (item1,item2,item3)) up
  )
SELECT S.[SID]
      ,T.[TID]
FROM TIDs T INNER JOIN SIDs S 
ON T.Items = S.Items
```

### Result

```
╔═════╦═════╗
║ SID ║ TID ║
╠═════╬═════╣
║   1 ║   1 ║
║   1 ║   2 ║
║   1 ║   4 ║
║   1 ║   5 ║
║   2 ║   1 ║
║   2 ║   3 ║
║   2 ║   4 ║
║   2 ║   3 ║
║   3 ║   1 ║
║   3 ║   3 ║
║   3 ║   4 ║
║   3 ║   1 ║
║   3 ║   3 ║
║   3 ║   5 ║
║   3 ║   3 ║
║   4 ║   1 ║
║   4 ║   2 ║
║   4 ║   4 ║
║   4 ║   5 ║
║   4 ║   1 ║
║   4 ║   3 ║
║   4 ║   5 ║
╚═════╩═════╝
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't compare the sets, you get too many results.

Comment: @Sean Would you like to elaborate your claim ?

Comment: M.Ali, thank you. Give me until tommorow to digest and understand your input, please. I'll come back to you.

Comment: @Nylix if you had your database normalised as it should have been, it would have been an easy query.

Comment: @M.Ali You are absolutely right. My database design was much too complicated. Thank you again. I learned a lot from your code example - even though it did not solve the problem 100%

Comment: How it did not solve the problem 100% where you are having issues ?

Comment: What I mentioned before, the required result is the sets that are fully contained in the transaction. i.e. SID 2, TID 1 is not valid in your result set because TID 1 does not have "l" in it. (which is part of SID 2.)